# Is there a list of news articles related to bitcoin?

Tags: news-coverage

What articles if any have been in the mainstream media about bitcoin?

Comment: Topic should be changed to "Is there a list of news articles related to bitcoin"? A press release is something different. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_release

Comment: You can find a list of articles about bitcoin here:
http://howmanycoins.com/#shortcodes

Comment: @ D.H. - symantics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most up-to-date list is the [Bitcoin press hits](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1958.0) thread. However, if you want a shorter list with more quality content, I recommend [Press](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Press) page on wiki.

Answer (score 6):

The most complete list I'm aware of is the [Bitcoin press hits](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1958.0) thread at bitcointalk.org .  But be aware that there is a **lot** of content there to sort through. BitCoin has been covered repeatedly in [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/2011/0509/technology-psilocybin-bitcoins-gavin-andresen-crypto-currency.html), [Wired](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2011-05/16/bitcoin-p2p-currency), the [Wall Street Journal](http://www.smartmoney.com/invest/stocks/the-currency-thats-up-200000-1307029053200/?link=SM_mustread), the [Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/30/business/economy/30views.html?scp=2&sq=bitcoin&st=cse), etc.

Answer (score 1):

BitcoinTalk has a [Press](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=77.0) board dedicated to discussing news articles. Each article has its own thread there, which amounts to about 7500 articles by now.

A lot of articles are also linked and discussed on [r/bitcoin](http://www.reddit.com/r/bitcoin), although they don't make up the brunt of the topics there.